# toggle switch back to off

Tags: javascript, html, css

I trying to create a function which reverts toggle switches back to off.
I'm turning a light on or off with my switch but there is a button and if i press that I want all the lights to turn off and the switches to turn to 'off'
As you can see there are 4 switches and a button to shut everything down. And I'm wondering how I can communicate between HTML, CSS and JS

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="one" id="one">
    <span class="slider round">
    </span> </label>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="two" id="two">
    <span class="slider round">
    </span> </label>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="three" id="three">
    <span class="slider round">
    </span> </label>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="four" id="four">
    <span class="slider round">
    </span> </label>
<br>
<input type="button" id="stop" value="Stop All" onclick="shutdown()"><br>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have created an example app for you here. https://codesandbox.io/embed/lucid-brook-q6qsq

The idea is to use `document.querySelectorAll` and iterate over all the checkboxes and uncheck them.  Here is the relevant code:

```
document.querySelector("#stop").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const switches = document.querySelectorAll(".switch input");
  for (let s of switches) {
    s.checked = false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you look up [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
    [...document.querySelectorAll(".switch input[type=checkbox]")].forEach(function(chk) {
      chk.checked = false; // and perhaps add chk.onchange() if needed
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="one" id="one">
    <span class="slider round">
    </span> </label>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="two" id="two">
    <span class="slider round">
    </span> </label>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="three" id="three">
    <span class="slider round">
    </span> </label>
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="four" id="four">
    <span class="slider round">
    </span> </label>
<br>
<input type="button" id="stop" value="Stop All" /><br>
```

Alternative code for ancient browsers

```
var chks = document.querySelectorAll(".switch input[type=checkbox]"); 
for (var i=0;i<chks.length;i++) chks[i].checked = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript you'll use the `getElementsByClassName()` method. You'll have to add a class to all of your checkboxes, alternatively you can use `getElementsByTagName()` to target the checkbox tags.

```js
let switches = document.getElementsByClassName("checkboxClass");
```

then iterate thru the class with JavaScript

```js
for (let i = 0; i < switches.length; i++) {
  switches[i].checked = false;
}
```

this will turn them all off. you can put this in a function and call it whenever (`onclick`/`onchange`, etc.)

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Note: The `switch` class is on the `<label>`s. Probably need to get the child `<input>`s before unchecking them. One way would be `document.querySelectorAll('.switch input')`, for example (not the downvoter, btw)

Comment: querySelectorAll is way better than having to add classes to each box

Comment: the users level suggest they are newer to JS, my code is simpler and less lines. i respect your opinion, but I think mine is better in this situation. also note where i recommend selecting by tag, you wouldn't need to add classes for that and he wouldn't have to use spread and pass a function in as a property. cheers

Comment: Simpler and less lines than what? You did not add any event handling which will add exactly as many lines as I have. And why not teach the best code from the start?

Comment: I can easily change my code to `const chks = document.querySelectorAll(".switch input[type=checkbox]"); for (let i=0;i<chks.length;i++) chks[i].checked = false; }`

Comment: you have valid points, so do i. your code is more advanced and you probably know more about JavaScript. congratulations. Let the OP select his answer, and enjoy the debate.